# LINQ Where Performance issues

Tags: performance, linq

I have the following code that takes approximately 17 seconds to do 1000 compares, I am hoping a little tweak to the code can improve the performance

```
 var cities = ExistingCities.Where(x =>
            (x.CityName == city || x.SubDomainName == city || (x.AlternativeNames != null && x.AlternativeNames.Contains(city))
                //country
             && (x.CountryName == country || x.CountryCode == country)
                //region
            && (x.RegionName == region || x.RegionCode == region)
            )
            ).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**
Apologies for not providing more info.

ExistingCities is a List< ImportCity > which I pre-populate from a database so I am not hitting the database constantly (ran out of connection pools in as I am using Parrallel.ForEach so I just preload them and then use LINQ to look for stuff, so far I have improved the performance quite a bit but I was hoping there was more can be done to what my final code look slike

```
    public class ImportCity
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string SubDomainName { get; set; }
    public string AlternativeNames { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public string RegionCode { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

}
```

AlternativeNames is just a long string that may contain the name

Comment: We can't really tell much without more context - what is `ExistingCities`? Where does it come from, and what is the compile-time type?

Comment: x.AlternativeNames.Contains(city) will look through AlternativeNames once for each element in ExistingCities.

Comment: So the question is; What is ALternativeNames.

If it is a big monster, you could probalby gain a lot by converting it to a dictionary.

Comment: Updated with more info..

Comment: Can you convert `AlternativeNames` to `HashSet<string>` (split by comma or by delimiter you have)? Also move `city` check condition to the end (after `country` and `region` checks).

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I believe it may be possible to split on comma (data is very dirty), assume it can be split on comma, what would I need to do further?

Comment: @Zoinky Just declare it as `HashSet<string> AlternativeNames { get; set; }` and initialize it as `importCity.AlternativeNames = new HashSet<string>(alternativeNamesString.Split(','));` where `alternativeNamesString` is your original string.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov just re-arranging the conditions improved it to 5 seconds now,  but i moved country check first, then region, then city

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov using HashSet route seem to be a little slower, it snow between 6-8 seconds vs the roughly 5.

Comment: Thank you all, I think i got it down to a acceptable timing of 5 seconds, @UlugbekUmirov if you like you can post ur comment about re-arranging and I can accept it as an answer. Thank you

Comment: @Zoinky Yes, it may be slower if `AlternativeNames` string typically is not long. It is good to hear that reordering helped.

Comment: you shouldn't be pulling the whole thing from the database, you should be filtering from the database as much as possible. SQL will be faster at filtering out the stuff you don't care about than C#

Comment: @DLeh as mentioned calling sql server in a Parrallel.ForEach, even if i set the maximum threads causes a lot of running out of connection pool exceptions and from my previous tests, using sql server to do the filtering in this particular case seems a lot slower